# Postgresql. Create database with template. Originated tablespace disk space rises

Tags: postgresql

Preconditions:

- Win7 OS
- few disks (may be RAM-disks) for EdiskTablespace, FdiskTablespace,
  ...
- DB1@EdiskTablespace; DB1 populated with some data (no matter what kind)
- FdiskTablespace - empty

1) Review 'EdiskTablespace' physical storage space at corresponding folder/disk

2) Execute:

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid) FROM pg_stat_activity 
WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname = 'DB1' AND pid <> pg_backend_pid();

CREATE DATABASE "DB2" 
WITH TEMPLATE "DB1"
TABLESPACE "FdiskTablespace"
;
```

3) Review again originated 'EdiskTablespace' physical storage space at corresponding folder/disk.

Actual:
**Originated** 'EdiskTablespace' **tablespace disk space rises.**
Is it expected behavior while creating DB with template to new tablespace, but initial tablespace rises???

Tested on PG10,11,12

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: How much does it increase by?

Comment: Does it really matter "how much"? Not minimum, believe me, but about 1/3 - 1/2 out of initial size.

Comment: The issue is ongoing and up... Waiting for your propositions